# Code to loop through all records in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need a code to loop through all the records in a table so I can extract some data. In addition to this, is it also possible to loop through filtered records and, again, extract data? Thanks!

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a pretty standard DAO recordset loop. You can see some examples at the following links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243789%28v=office.12%29.aspx
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/email/recordsetloop.htm

My own standard loop looks something like this:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Contacts")

'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        'Perform an edit
        rs.Edit
        rs!VendorYN = True
        rs("VendorYN") = True 'The other way to refer to a field
        rs.Update

        'Save contact name into a variable
        sContactName = rs!FirstName & " " & rs!LastName

        'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up
```

Comment: FYI, you should encapsulate your `rs.Close` as `If Not rs = Nothing Then Set rs.Close`.  If, for some reason, your Set statement fails, you're code will error here.  My 0.02c.

Answer (score 10):

In "References", import DAO 3.6 object reference.

```
private sub showTableData

dim db as dao.database
dim rs as dao.recordset

set db = currentDb
set rs = db.OpenRecordSet("myTable") 'myTable is a MS-Access table created previously

'populate the table
rs.movelast
rs.movefirst

do while not rs.EOF
   debug.print(rs!myField) 'myField is a field name in table myTable
   rs.movenext             'press Ctrl+G to see debuG window beneath
loop

msgbox("End of Table")

end sub
```

You can interate data objects like queries and filtered tables in different ways:

Trhough query:

```
private sub showQueryData

dim db as dao.database
dim rs as dao.recordset
dim sqlStr as string

sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM customers as c WHERE c.country='Brazil'"

set db = currentDb
set rs = db.openRecordset(sqlStr)

rs.movefirst

do while not rs.EOF
  debug.print("cust ID: " & rs!id & " cust name: " & rs!name)
  rs.movenext
loop

msgbox("End of customers from Brazil")

end sub
```

You should also look for "Filter" property of the recordset object to filter only the desired records and then interact with them in the same way (see VB6 Help in MS-Access code window), or create a "QueryDef" object to run a query and use it as a recordset too (a little bit more tricky). Tell me if you want another aproach.

I hope I've helped.

Comment: A few comments: there is no benefit to doing a .MoveLast before your .MoveFirst unless you require an accurate recordcount of the recordset. Otherwise, you're just wasting resources traversing to the end of the recordset and back to the beginning again for no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: I don't see that there is much utility of filtering an existing recordset. The expensive part of the process is opening the recordset. If you need a subset of records, then start with that filter. Otherwise, it doesn't make a lot of sense to filter a recordset and then do something with the results.

Comment: Hi David-W-Fenton, thanks for your advice. I just consider that, for small tables, populating recordset is worth to load data into memory and improve speed on methods like `seek`. Moving recordset to its end and then to its begin is also showed in Access help.

Comment: I think you've got it backwards -- the smaller the recordset, the less value there is to loading it into a recordset, because Jet is going to cache the entire small table in memory. SEEK should be avoided as it really serves no purpose whatsoever except in a very small subset of very special cases.

Comment: It's a good idea to [`rs.close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-close-method-dao) the recordset and `db.close` the database when you're finished with them.

Answer (score 8):

Found a good code with comments explaining each statement.
Code found at - [accessallinone](http://www.accessallinone.com/looping-through-a-recordset/)

```
Sub DAOLooping()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "tblTeachers"
'For the purposes of this post, we are simply going to make 
'strSQL equal to tblTeachers.
'You could use a full SELECT statement such as:
'SELECT * FROM tblTeachers (this would produce the same result in fact).
'You could also add a Where clause to filter which records are returned:
'SELECT * FROM tblTeachers Where ZIPPostal = '98052'
' (this would return 5 records)

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
'This line of code instantiates the recordset object!!! 
'In English, this means that we have opened up a recordset 
'and can access its values using the rs variable.

With rs


    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
    'We don’t know if the recordset has any records, 
    'so we use this line of code to check. If there are no records 
    'we won’t execute any code in the if..end if statement.    

        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        'It is not necessary to move to the last record and then back 
        'to the first one but it is good practice to do so.

        While (Not .EOF)
        'With this code, we are using a while loop to loop 
        'through the records. If we reach the end of the recordset, .EOF 
        'will return true and we will exit the while loop.

            Debug.Print rs.Fields("teacherID") & " " & rs.Fields("FirstName")
            'prints info from fields to the immediate window

            .MoveNext
            'We need to ensure that we use .MoveNext, 
            'otherwise we will be stuck in a loop forever… 
            '(or at least until you press CTRL+Break)
        Wend

    End If

    .close
    'Make sure you close the recordset...
End With

ExitSub:
    Set rs = Nothing
    '..and set it to nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

Recordsets have two important properties when looping through data, EOF (End-Of-File) and BOF (Beginning-Of-File). Recordsets are like tables and when you loop through one, you are literally moving from record to record in sequence. As you move through the records the EOF property is set to false but after you try and go past the last record, the EOF property becomes true. This works the same in reverse for the BOF property.

These properties let us know when we have reached the limits of a recordset.