# How can commas be inserted to seperate a list of values displayed in a field on an access form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a field on an access form populated with data from a query. The field will have multiple values for a single row and has to be seperated by commas whereever there is a space between values. The number of values on every row could be different and has to smartly seperate them by commas.

Also, there is another field which pulls in an integer value from a table and when displayed on a form it has to be appended by a dollar symbol on every row.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to convert space delimited values to comma delimited?

You should be able to do this by opening the table (or a query) and using Find and Replace (Ctrl+H).

Another way to accomplish it is to use the VBA Replace function. But how and where you use this function depends a lot on the design of your application and your intentions. Typically I would create a DAO loop and iterate through all rows, replacing spaces with commas using the Replace function. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864160/code-to-loop-through-all-records-in-ms-access) an example of that, without the Replace part.

In general, it's a very bad idea to store comma delimited values in a single field. Usually this is data that should be broken up and stored in a separate table, one row for each value.