# looping through the accessdata set from access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a access database. The database have a table. Table contain several fields including url field. 
I have created a form to migrate ms access data to oracle. 
Then I added a button to save data to the oracle. But before saving the url , some of the characters needed to be replaced by proper characters.

```
Private Sub Command59_Click()

    accesstableDataSet = currentAccessSheet.gettable('tableToMigrate')
    foreach ( record in accestableDataSet){
        rowUrl = record.url
        url = doencode(rowUrl)
        exportToMysql(url)

}
```

How can i do something like above by writing to a access form button ?

Comment: When you say "replaced by proper characters", can you be more specific? Can you give us some examples?

Comment: '(' to '+%28' and 'space' to '+' ............

Comment: Use a DAO Loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864160/code-to-loop-through-all-records-in-ms-access/5869361#5869361

Comment: rinjan (or HK1), please provide as an answer and select the answer as accepted.  That way others can be better helped.

Comment: Smandoli or HK1 , Can I mark comment as an answer ?

Comment: Rather than duplicate the answer to the question which @HK1 linked to, I am voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like DAO. I like [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ;) even if there are [some limitations in MS Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164825%28v=office.10%29.aspx), ADO provides access to a broader variety of data sources than DAO, and exposes some features of the Jet 4.0 database engine that aren't available from DAO.

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQL AS String, sUrl AS String

sSQL = "SELECT *" & vbCr & _
    "FROM TableToMigrate"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open sSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic
With rst
    'fill rst object
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    'proccess through the
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        'get Url and decode it
        sUrl = DecodeUrl(.Fields("Url"))
        ExportToMySQL(sUrl)
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
```

I assume that you know how to write **DecodeUrl** and **ExportToMySQL** functions/procedures ;)