# VBA to export MS Access table into Oracle table

Tags: vba, oracle

I am trying to insert ms access table into Oracle table using the below code. I get an error "table or view does not exist" at cn.Execute strSql line. I think the code is unable to identify the access table name. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Function test()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim ssqlFields As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ssql As String

Set db = CurrentDb

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM T_556_557_ORCL", dbOpenDynaset)

cn.Open ( _
"User ID = XXXX" & _
";Password=YYYY" & _
";Data Source=ABCD" & _
";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")

cn.CommandTimeout = 300
strSql = "INSERT INTO TDMTRDOP.TEST SELECT Ent_Ex_Summ,QTY FROM T_556_557_ORCL"
cn.Execute strSql

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: You will need to insert the contents of RS as "T_556_557_ORCL" won't exist in cn's database.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Will you be able to help me with the code? I just need to know how to reference the RS in the Insert statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864160/code-to-loop-through-all-records-in-ms-access